# System of equations can be interpreted as intersection of $3$ planes in $3$-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm struggling with this question.

[image]

I have worked out that attempting to solve for the $x_i$ leads to a contradiction, and that
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&4&6\\1&-2&1\\2&14&17\end{vmatrix}=0$$
So there is no solution for $x$. But what are the planes?

1. Three parallel planes
2. two parallel planes and one intersecting plane
3. three planes that intersect the other two but not at the same location [Link](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymakerintermediatealgebra/chapter/read-inconsistent-and-dependent-systems-in-three-variables/)

So I have narrowed down the answer to 3, 4, 5. Which one is it and how do we know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labelling the coefficient matrix's rows as $R_1,R_2,R_3$, we have $R_3=3R_1-R_2$ but $R_1$ and $R_2$ independent, but $3\cdot18-(-6)\ne-6$ so the third *equation* is not a linear combination of the first two. This means that

- the planes corresponding to $R_1$ and $R_2$ intersect in a line
- $R_3$'s plane is parallel to that line of intersection, but not parallel to the first two planes

Therefore the fifth answer is correct: there is no solution for $x$ even though none of the planes are parallel.

Comment: @Sam How is that a solution? The question only asks for the planes configuration!

Comment: i. x+4y+6z=18 ii. x-2y+z=-6  iii. 2x+4y+17z=-6  Because no two of those planes are parrallel then each pair have a line of intersection.  i. have normal $N_1$=<1.4.6>, likewise $N_2$=<1,-2,1> and $N_3$=<2,14,17>. Then N1xN2= <16,-5,-6> is the direction of the vector of the intersection of planes i and ii. Likewise N1XN3=<-16,5,6> is the direction of for the intesection of planes i and iii. therefore 2 lines are parallel and there is no common point of intersection to all three planes

Comment: @Sam Which means that, since there is no solution for $x$, the answer I gave is correct.

Comment: He is saying 2 lines are parallel though. Answer 5,states no line are parrellel

Comment: @Sam He is referring to the _**lines** of intersection between every two planes_, not the **planes** themselves. For answer 5, those three lines of intersection are all parallel.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the clarification